# differentiation for Trigonometric functions written as follows:-

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differentiate The following with respect to y?
D=sec x[image]

Comment: apply chain rule: $\frac{dD}{dy} = \frac{d\sec x}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy} = \sec x\tan x\frac{dx}{dy}$

Comment: Thanks sir @Ak19

Comment: You're welcome!